# how i can put a condition in do while loop where the program is running

Tags: c++-cli

I faced this problem and I tried to fix it but I couldn't please I need your help .. this is my code:

```
#pragma endregion
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    y=Convert::ToInt16(textBox1->Text);
    c=Convert::ToInt16(textBox3->Text);
    a=Convert::ToDouble(rand() % y);
    b=Convert::ToDouble(rand() % c);
    textBox2->Text = Convert::ToString(a);
    textBox4->Text = Convert::ToString(b);

    x1=0;
    x2=0;

    do
    {
        trafficlight(a,b,1,2);
    }while(i==0);//here is my problem i need condition to make the while loop working while the program is running
```

if I do click on the button it jumps to the while loop only without the previous code and I need the previous code to work and condition that makes the while loop working while the program is running ..

Comment: it's windows application form of c++

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but I think the issue is that you're staying in a while loop on the UI thread.

Instead, make the button handler start a [Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx), or a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx), or something like that, and do the work there.

If the `trafficlight` method does UI access, be sure to [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke.aspx) back onto the UI thread.